# Firebase Analytics Data Disparity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

We use firebase analyitcs for monitoring our android app. We recently released a **new version of the app on August the 6th** and noticed a disparity in the data being displayed on the dashboard. The data is from interval from **8th August** to **10th August**.

Data displayed:
[image: Data graphs screenshot]
Data (What it should be as per firebase definitions):

Assuming that the `Daily engagement` (which is defined as total engagement) and the daily engagement per user is correct

```
No. of active users = Daily engagement/ Daily engagement per user = 17h 28m 51s/ 5 min 2s = 208.38

Total no. of sessions = sessions per user x no. of active users= 1.4 x 208.38= 291.733
```

`Session duration should be = Daily engagement/ Total no. of sessions= 3 min 35 sec but its shown as 6min 40 sec` (check the screenshot)

Any help or explanation will be appreciated.

Thanks!

[Analytics Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpMHi.png)

Answer (score 2):

By default, a session starts after at least 10s of user engagement (after a period of at least 30m of no user engagement).  And so, whenever users use your app for a period of less than 10s, you will accrue user engagement without a session. This often occurs after launching a new version of your app, since users download it and open it for a short amount of time (sometimes inadvertently after the upgrade) before backgrounding it.

Comment: Is it then correct to assume Firebase Cohort Retention is calculated on the occurrence of the user_engagement-event and not session_start-event ?