# Discrepancies between Firebase console and BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have recently linked a Firebase project to BigQuery, the project contains both an iOS app and an Android app.
I need to run a query to export the count of the "session_start" event grouped by platform.
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  event_date,
  platform,
  count(case when event_name = 'session_start' then 1 else null end) as app_sessions
from
  `xxx.analytics_xxx.events_*`
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN "20191028" AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY
  event_date, platform
Order by
  event_date
```

I found differences between the query results and the Firebase console, the discrepancy does not occur for all the dates so I'm wondering why this is happening.
Am I querying the count of session_start in the wrong way?

**Update:**

The discrepancy is around 1% and the numbers I got from the query are greater than the ones I see in the console (I attached a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZp4Z.png) with some data from one of the platforms for clarification).
I read the post

[Discrepancies on “active users metric” between Firebase Analytics dashboard and BigQuery export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853347/discrepancies-on-active-users-metric-between-firebase-analytics-dashboard-and)

especially the part regarding the needed time for data to be fully uploaded. In my case I noticed the discrepancy for dates older than three days even if the difference is very little (I ran the query on the 14th).

I can live with these variances, since I'm new to BigQuery I would like to know whether I'm querying data in the right way or not. 
Indeed, I don't know if I should expect exactly the same numbers from BigQuery and the Firebase console or data from the two sources can be very close but small differences may occur.

Thank you

Comment: What is the typical variance you are seeing?  1%, 10%?  Is it larger for more recent dates?  Are these variances something you can live with?  Just getting a little more info before we start guessing.  There have also been similar questions added on SO about Firebase and BQ discrepancies (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853347/discrepancies-on-active-users-metric-between-firebase-analytics-dashboard-and)

Comment: @rtenha, thank you for your comment, I updated the post and I included a screenshot